# How do I automatically change a part of my data in my excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my formula:

=RSLINX|AIR_TESTER_DATA!'AIR_TESTER_EXCEL_CHASSIS_STRing[14,i],L1,C1'

The i needs to go from 1 to 500 in 500 rows. same column.  I have a search and replace function that works excellent for the 14.  I just am not sure how to sequentially change the i from 1 to 500?  Help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: A "For loop" is what you are looking for. For i = 1 to 500. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will write Number 1,2,3,4... on Cells A1 to A500

Edit: On Cells B1 to B500 this will add the following formula =5*i, it will multiply 5 times the number generated by the loop (1 to 500).

```
Sub TestLoop()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim formulaText As String
    For i = 1 To 500
        formulaText = "=5*" & i & "&" & """ Is The product of 5 * " & i & """"
        Range("A" & i).Value = "Number: " & i
        Range("B" & i).Formula = formulaText
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I replace the i with numerical sequence

Comment: I figured out where the issue was.  That sample got me started.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped.